# TextMate.app regex: remove all text after specific symbol?

Tags: regex, macos, textmate, nsregularexpression

How to remove all text in string after specific symbol (Regular Expression) in TextMate.app (Mac OS X editor).

I have a text like a:

bla asfhjsfjhasfjasjhf

I need remove all letters in text after "bla ", but save "bla "

Comment: Can you be more brief please...Post some examples, what specific symbol are you trying to remove text after?

Comment: Have a read through [Ask] to find out how to ask good questions on SO.

Comment: I have a text like a:

bla asfhjsfjhasfjasjhf
bla adhjdajdajh
bla dfsfasfsjhf
bla asdhadadjadjaf


I need remove all letters in text after "bla "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the symbol you want, and wrap it in `(...)` tags. That adds it to a capture group.
Outside of those group tags, use `.*$` to match everything else to the end of the line.
Replace the results with that capture group, using `\1` or `$1` depending on the regex engine's preference.

```
Search: (...something here...).*$
Replace: \1
```

You'll need to provide a lot more detail if you have specific questions, however.

Answer (score 3):

In Textmate Select Search and Replace.

Check Regular expression.

In the Find field type:

```
\character.*$
```

**Example**:

```
AL|Alabama
AK|Alaska
AS|American Samoa
AZ|Arizona
AR|Arkansas
```

I would Search:

```
\|.*$
```

Result:

```
AL
AK
AS
AZ
AR
```